# How to navigate with combination of default and simple arguments in jetpack compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-navigation

Here is my Screens object

```
  object AssignScreen :
        Screens("assign_screen/{${Constants.TRIP_ID}}?dockId={${Constants.DOCK_ID}}") {
        fun passTripAndDockId(tripId: String,dockId : String = ""): String {
            return "assign_dock_screen/$tripId?dockId=$dockId"
        }
    }
```

My navgraph

```
composable(
            Screens.AssignScreen.route,
            arguments = listOf(
                navArgument(Constants.TRIP_ID){
                    type = NavType.StringType
                },
                navArgument(Constants.DOCK_ID){
                    defaultValue = ""
                    type = NavType.StringType
                    nullable = true
                }
            )
        ){
            val tripID = it.arguments?.getString(Constants.TRIP_ID).toString()
        }
```

is my navigation line

```
navController.navigate(Screens.AssignScreen.passTripAndDockId(tripId = trip.id))}
```

Error is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation destination that matches request NavDeepLinkRequest{

what is wrong in my code?

Comment: Change `assign_dock_screen` to `assign_screen` in `passTripAndDockId` method.

Comment: ignore this i have used correct route in my code

Comment: Ok, edit you code to avoid doubt and include actual values of `Constants.TRIP_ID` and `Constants.DOCK_ID`. Also, add dummy composable inside current route, `Box` for example.

Comment: thanks, code is sorted I have mistakely not added braces after TRIP_ID